# How to set Icon for BlackBerry Application in JDE NetBeans

Tags: blackberry, netbeans, java-me, icons, blackberry-jde

I develope application for BlackBerry, I use JDE 7.1.0 and NetBeans 6.9
How to set Icon for BlackBerry Application in JDE NetBeans ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use only Netbeans, consider use of [BlackBerry Ant Tools](http://bb-ant-tools.sourceforge.net/docs#rapc)

There's ant task `rapc`

and it has a nested element `jdp`, and jdp has `icon` property.

Check the link I provided above. There is full documentation for BB Ant Tools.

If you use Netbans + JDE, then set icon in JDE, just add a picture to your project and specify it as app icon in application descriptor file.

Answer (score 1):

Go to `BlackBerry_App_Descriptor.xml` and there in the Application icons tab put your icon. Done.